# Display URL query string variable in a Wordpress page

Tags: wordpress

I want to dynamically display some text on a Wordpress page from the string variable.

Eg on this page webaddress.com/?**text**=**happy**

Would result in seeing this on the page:

"So, you are feeling **happy**."

I am not really a coder, is there a simple plugin for this? I imagine it would use shortcode like this:

"So, you are feeling **[text]**."

Sorry if my question is too basic.

Also I am not comfortable adding code to theme functions but am OK at adding CSS.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You will want this good sir: https://wordpress.org/plugins/get-params/

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

OMG. I just found a simple plugin to do this:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/url-params/

Sorry, I did not know how to search for a solution but as soon as I included shortcode in my search  - boom.

I hope I did not waste anybody's time.